# ElasticSearch - Ordering aggregation by nested aggregation on nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "itineraryId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "iid",
        "size": 2147483647,
        "order": [
          {
            "price>price>price.max": "desc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duration": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "drn"
          }
        },
        "price": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "prl"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "price": {
              "filter": {
                "terms": {
                  "prl.cc.keyword": [
                    "USD"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "price": {
                  "stats": {
                    "field": "prl.spl.vl"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I am getting the error:

> "Invalid terms aggregation order path [price>price>price.max].  Terms
> buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out
> of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final
> single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end.  Sub-path
> [price] points to non single-bucket aggregation"

query works fine if I order by duration aggregation like

```
"order": [
      {
        "duration.max": "desc"
      }
```

So is there any way to Order aggregation by nested aggregation on nested field i.e something like below ?

```
"order": [
      {
        "price>price>price.max": "desc"
      }
```

Comment: This is not supported yet, but a community pull request has just been submitted to address this issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/24121 Original issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16838

Comment: @Val Do you know any other workaround for this ?

Comment: Yes, add the maximum price as a new field at the root level.

Comment: @Val, Unfortunately that's not possible as prices array contains multiple price with some other fields like currencyCode, clientId, etc. on which I am applying filters.

Comment: Yes, but nothing prevents you from adding a `max_price` field at the root level (containing the MAX(price) from all nested `prices` elements) which you can then use for sorting your `iid` root-level buckets.

Comment: @val, sorry if i am not getting you, but max_price is specific to currency codes and client Ids so there will be multiple max_price

Comment: Then you can have a `max_price` object with one price per currency `"max_price": {"USD": 1000, "EUR": 1210, ...}`

Comment: @Val but by doing that, don't you think max_price will become nested field and same problem will occur ?

Comment: No, because there will only be a single value per currency (always the max price for any nested currency). You can then add another `max` sub-aggregation on `max_price.USD` and sort the `iid` terms with it.

Comment: Oh, I got you now. thanks.

Comment: @val, So it will be like "max_price": {
    "Client1_USD": 1000,
    "Client1_EUR": 1210,
    "Client2_USD": 1000,
    "Client2_EUR": 1210
  }
right ?

Comment: what's the approximate cartesian product (client X currency) in your nested array?

Comment: @Val, price can be different for different customers. for one customer, max_price can be 100 USD and for another customer, max_price can be 150 USD

Comment: Yeah, my question was how many different nested elements do you have on average in the `prices` array?

Comment: approximate 500 clients and 100 currencies

Comment: Which means you might end up with 50,000 elements in your nested `prices` array? In my opinion this is a **really** bad idea, you might want to change your design in order to better denormalize your data.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am also worried about.

Comment: Ok, we'll stop here as we're diverging in respect to the original question. Feel free to ask another design-related question if you feel the need to.

Answer (score 1):

As Val has pointed out in the comments ES does not support it yet.

Till then you can first aggregate the nested aggregation and then use the reverse nested aggregation to aggregate the duration, that is present in the root of the document.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html

Comment: @J Aamish - I think thats not possible for nested field price. And on duration field, ordering already works as stated in the question.